# Parse txt - search for string, if found parse numbers from line below

Tags: c++, parsing, text, text-parsing

im a bit lost. Trying to build a parser that searches for certain text, if found, outputs the number(s) below.

Here is my Sample.txt

```
#BTC/USDT

Client: Binance Futures
Trade Type: Regular (LONG)
Leverage: Isolated (10.0X)

Entry Zone:
19000 - 18980

Take-Profit Targets:
1) 19195 - 20%
2) 19365 - 20%
3) 19580 - 20%
4) 19805 - 20%
5) 20000 - 20%

Stop Targets:
1) 18600 - 100.0%
```

Here is my super basic Code so far:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

std::string coinpair = ""; // wip
std::string entry = "Entry Zone:";
std::string taprof = "Take-Profit Targets";
std::string stoploss = "Stop Targets";
std::string leaverage = ""; // wip


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::fstream myfile("C:\\Projects\\Sample.txt", std::ios_base::in);

    std::string file_contents;

    while (std::getline(myfile, entry))
    {
        file_contents += entry;
        file_contents.push_back('\n');
        cout << entry << ' ';
    }

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Now I am a little too stupid to do exactly what I want, as its parsing the full txt.

What I need is: Search Entry Zone: and parse the numbers from the new line below. I hope that someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: What's the question? You've read every line. Now you just need to use what you've read. You might try looking for colons. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/

Comment: The question is: what it needs to parse the numbers right under; Entry Zone: (19000 - 18980) and only this both numbers, before i go deeper and parse the numbers of Take-Profit Targets.

Sadly im totaly lost at it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you can read and identify that particular line.
I'll assume that you can parse the lines within a section.
Those are easy parsing. You might use http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/ to locate the colon.

Apparently the question is when to do what. Consider a simple state machine. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

When you read a line, you are either looking for the next section to start, or currently reading lines for a specific section. Therefore, you just need a state variable to remember which one you are currently doing.

Here is a simple state machine implementation, without the parsing details:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

enum state { top_level, section_level };

std::string parse_section_name(const std::string& line) {
    // if this line starts a section, return the section name
    // returning a non-empty string will change state to "section_level"
    return line;
}

bool parse_entry(const std::string& section, const std::string& line) {
    // return true if this was a valid data line in the section
    // returning false will change state to "top_level"
    return (line.size());
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::fstream myfile("C:\\Projects\\Sample.txt", std::ios_base::in);

    state current_state = top_level;
    std::string line;
    std::string section_name;
    while (std::getline(myfile, line))
    {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
        switch (current_state) {
        case top_level:
            section_name = parse_section_name(line);
            if (section_name.size())
                current_state = section_level;
            break;

        case section_level:
            if (!parse_entry(section_name, line))
                current_state = top_level;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```